# Attrs not being rendered in HTML using Django-Tables2

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

Based on the [Django-Tables2 documentation](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-attributes.html), it seems pretty straightforward to add custom attributes to any column, and I did so:

```
class NameTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column(attrs={"td":{"class":"my-class"}})
    office = tables.Column(attrs={"td":{"class":"my-class2"}})
    class Meta:
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ("name", "office")
```

I pass my data to this class by means of:

```
data = [{'name':'John','office':'L.A'},{'name':'Michael','office':'N.Y.'}]
table = NameTable(data)
template_name = 'planning/index.html'
return render(request, template_name, {"table": table})
```

Unfortunately, even if the data is rendered correctly in the table, I cannot find the tags I have previously defined (my-class and my-class2) nor the class "paleblue" defined inside the meta class in any point of the HTML source code after rendering (which of course means CSS is not being applied correctly).

What am I missing?

Comment: refresh your browser

Comment: Already did, and tried even in private browsing

Comment: your code is correct, you template use `{% render_table table%}`?

Comment: I really do not know what was wrong, but after all, this morning it was all working correctly. I suspect maybe some cache was still in use even in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm replying to myself with a piece of advice: always use Control+F5 when refreshing instead of just F5.